# Is it correct to say "you have an innovative approach to something” or "an approach for"? (The recruitment and management of personnel.)

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say "you have an innovative approach **to** something” or "an approach **for**"? (The recruitment and management of personnel.) 
Trying to finish English assignment.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: *Approach* here takes the preposition *to*. HTH.

Comment: *To* specifies the target of the approach. *For* specifies the agent of the approach. An innovative approach *to* traveling *for* someone who doesn't even have a passport. An interesting approach *to* playing the violin *for* someone who only plays the piano. A brilliant approach *to* managing people *for* someone who's never managed people before.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely **TO.**  "Approach" indicates direction **to**ward a concept.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for your answer. This answer has been flagged by the system as a possible low quality post due to its length and content. Just so you're aware, this community values well thought out answers that help the questioner learn and understand English better. I don't think that this answer meets that standard. Since you're new I won't recommend deleting it but will ask you to explain more clearly why you think it's correct and change the language to be more respectful. Read some answers with lots of votes if you want an example of what's expected.